# Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

:25:23: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
BottomTabBtn(imagePath: "assets/images/tab_home.png"),
^
lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:37:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
BottomTabBtn(this.imagePath);
^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:26:23: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
BottomTabBtn(imagePath: "assets/images/tab_search.png"),
^
lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:37:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
BottomTabBtn(this.imagePath);
^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:27:23: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
BottomTabBtn(imagePath: "assets/images/tab_saved.png"),
^
lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:37:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
BottomTabBtn(this.imagePath);
^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:28:23: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
BottomTabBtn(imagePath: "assets/images/tab_logout.png"),
^
lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:37:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
BottomTabBtn(this.imagePath);
^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 56s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomTabs extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(12.0)
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
            spreadRadius: 1.0,
            blurRadius: 30.0,
          )
        ]
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          BottomTabBtn(imagePath: "assets/images/tab_home.png"),
          BottomTabBtn(imagePath: "assets/images/tab_search.png"),
          BottomTabBtn(imagePath: "assets/images/tab_saved.png"),
          BottomTabBtn(imagePath: "assets/images/tab_logout.png"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomTabBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? imagePath;
  BottomTabBtn(this.imagePath);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 22.0,
        horizontal: 16.0
      ),
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage(
          imagePath ?? "assets/images/tab_home.png"
        ),
        width: 22.0,
        height: 22.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You  are giving named arguments in constructor so either remove named arguments or make constructor like this so that it can accept named parameters : `BottomTabBtn({this.imagePath});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify the parameter label for BottomTabBtn. Instead of:

```
BottomTabBtn(imagePath: "assets/images/tab_home.png"),
```

Use:

```
BottomTabBtn("assets/images/tab_home.png"),
```

If you really want to use parameter label, then change your constructor declaration to:

```
BottomTabBtn({this.imagePath});
```

Comment: Can you help me with this error too :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251155/a-renderflex-overflowed-by-99241-pixels-on-the-bottom-null-check-operator-used/68251619#68251619