# A RenderFlex overflowed by 99241 pixels on the bottom & Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building BottomTabBtn(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BottomTabBtn file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:35:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ScrollPosition.viewportDimension (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:172:53)
#1      _PagePosition.getPixelsFromPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:382:19)
#2      PageController.animateToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:197:16)
#3      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/screens/home_page.dart:61:35)
#4      _BottomTabsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:39:33)
...
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building BottomTabBtn(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BottomTabBtn file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:42:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ScrollPosition.viewportDimension (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:172:53)
#1      _PagePosition.getPixelsFromPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:382:19)
#2      PageController.animateToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:197:16)
#3      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/screens/home_page.dart:61:35)
#4      _BottomTabsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:46:33)
...
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building BottomTabBtn(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BottomTabBtn file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:49:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ScrollPosition.viewportDimension (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:172:53)
#1      _PagePosition.getPixelsFromPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:382:19)
#2      PageController.animateToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:197:16)
#3      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/screens/home_page.dart:61:35)
#4      _BottomTabsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:53:33)
...
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building BottomTabBtn(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BottomTabBtn file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:56:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ScrollPosition.viewportDimension (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:172:53)
#1      _PagePosition.getPixelsFromPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:382:19)
#2      PageController.animateToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:197:16)
#3      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/screens/home_page.dart:61:35)
#4      _BottomTabsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:60:33)
...
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 399607 pixels on the right.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Row file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:32:14
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

```
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#7c268 relayoutBoundary=up3 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(392.7, 100000.0)
...  direction: horizontal
...  mainAxisAlignment: spaceAround
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
  child 1: RenderErrorBox#ee73a
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: Size(100000.0, 100000.0)
  child 2: RenderErrorBox#3f178
    parentData: offset=Offset(100000.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: Size(100000.0, 100000.0)
  child 3: RenderErrorBox#4099b
    parentData: offset=Offset(200000.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: Size(100000.0, 100000.0)
  child 4: RenderErrorBox#2956f
    parentData: offset=Offset(300000.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: Size(100000.0, 100000.0)
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99241 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Column file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/screens/home_page.dart:28:13
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

```
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#1474e relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=759.3)
...  size: Size(392.7, 759.3)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: spaceBetween
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building BottomTabBtn(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BottomTabBtn file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:35:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ScrollPosition.viewportDimension (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:172:53)
#1      _PagePosition.getPixelsFromPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:382:19)
#2      PageController.animateToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:197:16)
#3      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/screens/home_page.dart:61:35)
#4      _BottomTabsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:39:33)
...
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building BottomTabBtn(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BottomTabBtn file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:42:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ScrollPosition.viewportDimension (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:172:53)
#1      _PagePosition.getPixelsFromPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:382:19)
#2      PageController.animateToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:197:16)
#3      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/screens/home_page.dart:61:35)
#4      _BottomTabsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:46:33)
...
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building BottomTabBtn(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BottomTabBtn file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:49:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ScrollPosition.viewportDimension (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:172:53)
#1      _PagePosition.getPixelsFromPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:382:19)
#2      PageController.animateToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:197:16)
#3      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/screens/home_page.dart:61:35)
#4      _BottomTabsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:53:33)
...
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building BottomTabBtn(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BottomTabBtn file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:56:11
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ScrollPosition.viewportDimension (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:172:53)
#1      _PagePosition.getPixelsFromPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:382:19)
#2      PageController.animateToPage (package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart:197:16)
#3      _HomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/screens/home_page.dart:61:35)
#4      _BottomTabsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:your_store/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:60:33)
...
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 399607 pixels on the right.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Row file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:32:14
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

```
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#4004c relayoutBoundary=up3 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(392.7, 100000.0)
...  direction: horizontal
...  mainAxisAlignment: spaceAround
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
  child 1: RenderErrorBox#db496
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: Size(100000.0, 100000.0)
  child 2: RenderErrorBox#73a53
    parentData: offset=Offset(100000.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: Size(100000.0, 100000.0)
  child 3: RenderErrorBox#b66f8
    parentData: offset=Offset(200000.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: Size(100000.0, 100000.0)
  child 4: RenderErrorBox#d20be
    parentData: offset=Offset(300000.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
    size: Size(100000.0, 100000.0)
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
```

====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99241 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Column file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/screens/home_page.dart:28:13
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

```
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#293da relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=759.3)
...  size: Size(392.7, 759.3)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: spaceBetween
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
```

====================================================================================================

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? selectedTab;
  final Function(int)? tabPressed;
  BottomTabs({this.selectedTab, this.tabPressed});

  @override
  _BottomTabsState createState() => _BottomTabsState();
}

class _BottomTabsState extends State<BottomTabs> {
  int _selectedTab = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _selectedTab = widget.selectedTab ?? 0;

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0), topRight: Radius.circular(12.0)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
              spreadRadius: 1.0,
              blurRadius: 30.0,
            )
          ]),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          BottomTabBtn(
            imagePath: "assets/images/tab_home.png",
            selected: _selectedTab == 0 ? true : false,
            onPressed: () {
              widget.tabPressed!(0);
            },
          ),
          BottomTabBtn(
            imagePath: "assets/images/tab_search.png",
            selected: _selectedTab == 1 ? true : false,
            onPressed: () {
              widget.tabPressed!(1);
            },
          ),
          BottomTabBtn(
            imagePath: "assets/images/tab_saved.png",
            selected: _selectedTab == 2 ? true : false,
            onPressed: () {
              widget.tabPressed!(2);
            },
          ),
          BottomTabBtn(
            imagePath: "assets/images/tab_logout.png",
            selected: _selectedTab == 3 ? true : false,
            onPressed: () {
              widget.tabPressed!(3);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomTabBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? imagePath;
  final bool? selected;
  final Function? onPressed;
  BottomTabBtn({this.imagePath, this.selected, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _selected = selected ?? false;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed!(),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 28.0, horizontal: 24.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
                top: BorderSide(
          color: _selected ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Colors.transparent,
          width: 2.0,
        ))),
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage(imagePath ?? "assets/images/tab_home.png"),
          width: 22.0,
          height: 22.0,
          color: _selected ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Put your `BottomTabButton` in an expanded widget and set same flex for all. (I believe the image you are using is too big, probably that can be a reason for that error, not sure. Need to further check)

Comment: Regarding the null error, the tabPressed will be null and you are trying to forcefully use that by putting !

Comment: Without using (!) a null checker it's showing me an error to use a null checker.

Comment: Either use ? or ??, if you are not sure whether the property has the value or not

Comment: Can you please correct my code and help me

Comment: I can share a zip file of my code if that's fine with you?

Comment: Here is the link: 
https://github.com/Bhaskar2510/Your-Store-Final-Sem-Project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to first set a proper width and height to your custom tab-bar and use expanded widget to your tab items with equal flex.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? selectedTab;
  final Function(int)? tabPressed;

  BottomTabs({this.selectedTab, this.tabPressed});

  @override
  _BottomTabsState createState() => _BottomTabsState();
}

class _BottomTabsState extends State<BottomTabs> {
  int _selectedTab = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _selectedTab = widget.selectedTab ?? 0;

    return Container(
      height: 56, // Set height as per your need
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // Screen Width
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0), topRight: Radius.circular(12.0)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
              spreadRadius: 1.0,
              blurRadius: 30.0,
            )
          ]),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1, // Expanded with flex 1 for all items
            child: BottomTabBtn(
              imagePath: "assets/images/tab_home.png",
              selected: _selectedTab == 0 ? true : false,
              onPressed: () {
                widget.tabPressed!(0);
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: BottomTabBtn(
              imagePath: "assets/images/tab_search.png",
              selected: _selectedTab == 1 ? true : false,
              onPressed: () {
                print("pressed search");
                widget.tabPressed!(1);
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: BottomTabBtn(
              imagePath: "assets/images/tab_saved.png",
              selected: _selectedTab == 2 ? true : false,
              onPressed: () {
                widget.tabPressed!(2);
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: BottomTabBtn(
              imagePath: "assets/images/tab_logout.png",
              selected: _selectedTab == 3 ? true : false,
              onPressed: () {
                widget.tabPressed!(3);
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I found one issue with your gesture on pressed and I've corrected that as well:

```dart
class BottomTabBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? imagePath;
  final bool? selected;
  final Function? onPressed;

  BottomTabBtn({this.imagePath, this.selected, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _selected = selected ?? false;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        onPressed!();
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
                top: BorderSide(
          color: _selected ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Colors.transparent,
          width: 2.0,
        ))),
        child: Center(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage(imagePath ?? "assets/images/tab_home.png"),
            width: 22.0,
            height: 22.0,
            color: _selected ? Theme.of(context).accentColor : Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Final outcome:

[image: Bottom Tab]

Comment: Hey! Can you please help me with this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72435347/flutter-how-to-call-images-from-api/72665553#72665553

Comment: I didn't un accept the answer actually my little brother was playing on my laptop he's in grade 6 so I'm teaching him a bit of the internet too and he's just 10 so he might have done that unintentionally. Cuz I was using this tab and it was open I just switched the window but I guessed he switched it back and thought it was a game cuz the UI might have looked like a game of ticks and crosses to him...no hard feeling if you don't wanna help just clarifying cuz I don't want that anyone thinks that I don't value their efforts and time they put on to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can handle this:

1. Read the details of the log which provides a hint as to next steps. Line 32 is the offendor. Add an Expanded widget so that the row is properly constrained.

"The relevant error-causing widget was: Row file:///C:/Users/bhask/StudioProjects/your_store/lib/widgets/bottom_tabs.dart:32:14 The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal. The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size. This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView."

2. If using Android Studio you can click on "Flutter Inspector" which can help you narrow down the offending widget and test out various options to remove the overflow.

My guess: 99241 pixels is a lot! If your assets (assets/images/tab_home.png) are not scaled properly. You can potentially verify these are the specific offenders by replacing them with an Icon() widget.

Comment: Can you give me an example of it by correcting my code, please?